# Function point to kloc ratio as a software metric... the "Name That Tune" metric?

Tags: functional-programming, metric

What do you think of using a metric of function point to lines of code as a metric?

It makes me think of the old game show "Name That Tune".  "I can name that tune in three notes!"  I can write that functionality in 0.1 klocs!  Is this useful?

It would certainly seem to promote library usage, but is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a terrible idea.  Just as bad as paying programmers by lines of code that they write.

In general, I prefer concise code over verbose code, but only as long as it still expresses the programmers' intention clearly.  Maximizing function points per kloc is going to encourage everyone to write their code as briefly as they possibly can, which goes beyond concise and into cryptic.  It will also encourage people to join adjacent lines of code into one line, even if said joining would not otherwise be desirable, just to reduce the number of lines of code.  The maximum allowed line length would also become an issue.

Answer (score 0):

KLOC is tolerable if you strictly enforce code standards, kind of like using page requirements for a report: no putting five statements on a single line or removing most of the whitespace from your code.

I guess one way you could decide how effective it is for your environment is to look at several different applications and modules, get a rough estimate of the quality of the code, and compare that to the size of the code. If you can demonstrate that code quality is consistent within your organization, then KLOC isn't a bad metric.

In some ways, you'll face the same battle with any similar metric. If you count feature or function points, or simply features or modules, you'll still want to weight them in some fashion. Ultimately, you'll need some sort of subjective supplement to the objective data you'll collect.

Answer (score 0):

"What do you think of using a metric of function point to lines of code as a metric?"

Don't get the question.  The above ratio is -- for a given language and team -- a simple statistical fact.  And it tends toward a mean value with a small standard deviation.

There are lots of degrees of freedom: how you count function points, what language you're using, how (collectively) clever the team is.  If you don't change those things, the value stays steady.

After a few projects together, you have a solid expectation that 1200 function points will be 12,000 lines of code in your preferred language/framework/team organization.

KSloc / FP is a bare statistical observation.  Clearly, there's something else about this that's bothering you.  Could you be more specific in your question?

Answer (score 0):

All metrics suck. My theory has always been that if you *have* to have them, then use the easiest thing you can to gather them and be done with it and onto important things.

That generally means something along the lines of

```
grep -c ";" *.h *.cpp | awk -F: '/:/ {x += $2} END {print x}'
```

If you are looking for a "metric" to track code efficency, don't. If you insist, again try something stupid but easy like source file size (see grep command above, w/o the awk pipe) or McCabe (with a counter program).

Answer (score 0):

The metric of Function Points to Lines of Code is actually used to generate the language level charts (actually, it is Function Points to Statements) to give an approximate sense of how powerful a programming language is.  Here is an example: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~timm/dm/functionpoints.html

I wouldn't recommend using that ratio for anything else, except high level approximations like the language level chart.

Promoting library usage is a good thing, but the other thing to keep in mind is you will lose in the ratio when you are building the libraries, and will only pay it off with dividends of savings over time.  Bean-counters won't understand that.

I personally would like to see a Function point to ABC metric ratio -- as I am curious about how the ABC metric (which indicates size and includes complexity as part of the info) would relate - perhaps linear, perhaps exponential, etc...  www.softwarerenovation.com/ABCMetric.pdf